# C# Try/Catch statement, am i doing this right?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace Something
{
    class MainProgram
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello? am I working?")
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nah I ain't working");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just poking about with C#, and I wanted to try errorchecking and whatnot. There's the code and the console. Does Catch{} just not do syntax errors?

Comment: C# is a compiled language. This means that all the code (including your `catch`) must compile first before anything can run. A syntax error is therefore an absolute barrier to any error handling you write yourself; the compiler never gets around to emitting code for it, let alone running it. In some sense your program is not even considered to be C# at all, so you might equally well have written `Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!"); Also, I want a banana` and then ask why `Hello, world!` isn't getting printed.

Comment: Please add code as text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: You have skipped `;` that's why it *doesn't compile*. It should be `Console.WriteLine("Hello? I am working");` - please, note `;` at the very end

Comment: Read this for a decent rundown on this try/catch stuff. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/csharp-try-catch/

Comment: Technically, `try {..} catch {...}` syntax is correct in your code (just put omitted `;`); however, you have *nothing* to catch: you just print a constant string. If only you read a string from a *file* (which can be locked, protected, not exist etc.), *database* (connection to which can be broken) etc exception catching will be meanful

Comment: If you have code, please post it as *text*, not an image

Comment: Please never write `catch {` or even `catch (Exception ex) {`. You should only ever catch ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle.

Answer (score 2):

Catch only catches runtime errors. This can be seen as you specify what it will catch and there is no type you specify in the catch that represents syntax errors.

If there is a syntax error, there is no program that runs the catch in the first place. The syntax error is issued by the compiler before the program exists and then is run, this is because C# is a compiled language. An editor or IDE can give you an early heads-up as well, but they also don't run your program to issue those errors.

And yes, you can use a catch without specifying the type of `Exception`, but that's just a shortcut for catching all errors which derive from `Exception` so it is a shortcut for `catch (Exception e)`

In other languages, such as JavaScript, which is an interpreted language, the interpreter (as opposed to a compiler) runs JavaScript code until it finds an error. So you can possibly have a partially run program that has syntax errors in it.

---

JavaScript example, just for fun:

`try { eval('func);'); } catch (e) { console.log('The error is a syntax error: ', e instanceof SyntaxError); }`

This will output "The error is a syntax error:  true" because it tries to run `func);` which is syntactically malformed. The SyntaxError was actually issued during runtime (remember, this is JavaScript not C#).

Comment: Technically speaking, Javascript is a compiled language also, at least as far as syntax is concerned, see https://jsfiddle.net/5gxe0osL/. You are just using `eval` to compile and execute something at runtime, you can do the same thing in C#

Comment: Hi @Charlieface. Compilation implies the creation of "things" other than the code which are the output of the compilation. These things are sometimes referred to as object files, and when "linked" they create the final compiled executable. JavaScript is interpreted. The jsfiddle doesn't show anything other than my code snippet. Thanks!

Comment: If you look carefully at the fiddle, you will see it's different from your snippet: it contains a syntax error in the main part of the code, not the `eval` so the `catch` never runs. In other words: the Javascript block still has to be compiled as a unit. Compilation does *not* have to include linking, it can also refer just to the compilation of the syntax tree from the code.

Comment: I see that now, thanks. This case doesn't mean that JavaScript is compiled. It means that the interpreter is unable to interpret and so doesn't process anything at all. This is why I used eval to create the syntax error, so that it at least runs. I'm not sure how u can get a syntax error without eval. Maybe refrence a separate file? Anyways JS is definitely not a compiled language.

Comment: Thank you, yes. Good to have that knowledge about compiled/interpreted languages, I'd not looked into that before. I've come from doing about 50% of a Python course, that being an interpreted language, but upon testing that doesn't really happen for its Try/Except functions either. Interesting Java though, looking into that up next after C#  yes

Comment: @Ghost Note that JavaScript is different than Java. "JavaScript is an interpreted language, not a compiled language. A program such as C++ or Java needs to be compiled before it is run." ~ from https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs98si/slides/overview.html#:~:text=JavaScript%20is%20an%20interpreted%20language,machine%20understands%20and%20can%20execute.

Comment: So Java is a compiled language just like C# while JavaScript is similar to Python in that they are both interpreted

Answer (score 1):

Try/Catch is not for SyntaxErrors, but Runtime errors. You can do

```
try{
  // Code here
} catch(Exception e){
  // log the exception
} finally{
  // code here will run no matter what (with or without errors)
}
```

As you can see, catch can optionally take a `Exception` parameter that can help you log it better. In your case, you will catch all exceptions, but you don't have a reference to the exception.

Try catch is usually used for cases like reading from a file/database, making web requests, etc. All these things may fail for external reasons but they are Syntax-wise correct.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` absolutely can cause an `IOException` (and is correctly documented to do so), since program output could be redirected, so that (for example) a full disk can cause it to fail. It's true that you'd almost never check for these kinds of errors, but they can definitely happen.

Comment: "others are necessary" - not quite, you can have `try { } finally { }` without catch

Comment: Thanks for the note. I will edit the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered but just to give you confidence the others are correct yes.

You typically will try to do something for example simply call a method or do some complicated logic you want to make sure doesn't exit out so you would write:

try{ XYZ } catch(Exception e){}

if you know the kind of exception that you are going to encounter whether it be a argumentoutofrange exception or nullpointerexception or anything specific like that you can change the catch to focus on that type.

The general Exception type is okay for working out issues when you don't know exactly what the problem is but I would say find out what the exception is and cater your response to best deal with it.

Sorry this was very wordy I just think understanding is more important since you seem new.